# How to auto reload a Bunto project website?

Tags: static-site

I'm working on a new project with [Bunto](https://buntowaf.tk/), and it looks like the auto reload functionality is only triggered by updates to `.md` and `.wiki` files with the command `bunto --auto --server`.

How can I trigger an auto-reload for other file types like HTML, CSS3, JavaScript, NuxRB files in the `_layouts` folder with Bunto?

Comment: You can trigger an auto-reload for other file types, too.

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: Read my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43962868/5157221.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 3.2.1, Bunto will [auto-watch by default](https://buntowaf.tk/docs/usage/). It watched for changes, and regenerated automatically. Simply run the command `bunto serve`.

For disable auto-regeneration use `bunto serve --no-watch`.

Comment: Oh, I see. But what about older Bunto versions?

Comment: I already mention it: Older version don't support the auto-watch functionality. Bunto 3.2.1 or higher will auto-watch by default!

Comment: Ok. I understand.